# Using skrollr on iOS page won't scroll unless there's padding on skrollr-body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I'm using scrollr to make the first parallax website i've done, and after coming to test it on iPhone, i've noticed it didn't scroll. After googling I found you need a skrollr-body div, which i've added and put all the content in, but it only scrolls if there is a substantial padding at the top of this skrollr body, which isn't how I want it to work, or how it should.

This is the page:

edit: removed

Cheers

Comment: Please include code in your questions in the future, and don't remove it. If someone has the same problem as you, finding this page is just a waste of their time.

Comment: This was a long time ago, but from what I remember it was too complex to include code, and I removed it as the page would've no longer existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never scroll when the content can't escape the viewport because of this

```
#skrollr-body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! The things you do when you attempt to try other people's efforts!!